# Feasible List in Dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I need some help with my thesis. I have a large excel file that includes routes. I only use two columns, one of them is origin postal code and the other one is destination postal code. I want to create a feasible list.
Excel file is something like that:

```
 - ID Origin_PC Destination_PC
 - 1  1900      1910
 - 2  1900      1911
 - 3  1901      1911
 - 4  1901      1912
```

I need a dictionary as:

```
{1900 : (1910, 1911), 1901 : (1911, 1912) ...}
```

So, I only want to create the dictionary and combine the same keys. If I didn't explain clearly sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas groupby:

```
import pandas as pd
# your input example, I suggest you use the Pandas read_csv function
data = {'ID': [1,2,3,4], 'Origin_PC': [1900, 1900, 1901, 1901], 'Destination_PC': [1910, 1911, 1911, 1912]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# the grouping that you are after
df.groupby('Origin_PC').Destination_PC.unique().to_dict()
```

Output:

```
>>> {1900: array([1910, 1911]), 1901: array([1911, 1912])}
```